Latex error: "Package natbib: Citation 'citation_1' on page 1 undefined
I facing a issue with natbib. It was working fine a few days ago, then i added a citation in my main.bib file, and now natbib is making problem again T.T
Problem:
I have a main.tex file, and I'm using \usepackage{natbib} to manage the bibliography references. The references are added in a file called main.bib, and at the end of my main.text I have
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{main}

Here a citation in the text:
This is a citation: \citep{Wimmer_2023}.

And here the reference in main.bib:
@article{Wimmer_2023,
    author = {Wimmer, John},
    title = {A Comprehensive Study on Something},
    journal = {Journal of Something Studies},
    year = {2023},
    volume = {15},
    number = {2},
    pages = {123-145}
}

What I have tried:
I tried some suggestions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323779/citation-not-working-in-latex-using-natbib-package.

Moved images in a separated folder.
Both file with same name: main.tex and main.bib
\usepackage{natbib} before \being{document}
deleted all auxiliares files (.aux, .blg, .bbl) and recompiled again (after that no .blg and .bbl was generated again).

But nothing solved the issue. Has anyone an idea what is the problem and how to solve it?
Log File:
Overfull \vbox (5.52498pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []

 [8]
chapter 1.

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wimmer_2023' on page 1 undefined on input line 153.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wimmer_2023' on page 1 undefined on input line 166.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Wimmer_2023' on page 1 undefined on input line 166.

[1




]
chapter 6.
No file main.bbl.

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

[29] (./main.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2020/03/25>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14474 strings out of 474115
 257867 string characters out of 5747697
 1949190 words of memory out of 5000000
 36249 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 617774 words of font info for 315 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 108i,16n,107p,10968b,518s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fpl/fplrc8a.pfb><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfsx1200.pfb><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfsx1440.pfb><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfsx1728.pfb><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/palatino/uplb8a.pfb><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/palatino/uplr8a.pfb><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/palatino/uplri8a.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (39 pages, 325137 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 170 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 112 compressed objects within 2 object streams
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 71686 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 74296 (max. 10000000)


Sorry, I forgot to explicitly explain the problem.
Problem:
After compiling, the references were not being added to the text, and I was getting the warning: "citation undefined."
Solution:
I think the issue was related to the VS Code compilation process. It wasn't executing BibTeX after every change, which is why it wasn't finding the new references added to the file.
I ran BibTeX manually in the terminal, and now the auxiliary files (bbl and blg) were created, and everything is working.
Thanks for your help!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

after any change in the bib file you need to run bibtex to generate the bibliography. latex never reads the bib file.

No file main.bbl means that you have not run bibtex, and all citations will be undefined.

Because of your answer it seems, this is indeed a duplicate …
